# Azure ML custom image tag and registry

Tags: machine-learning, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-devops-pipelines

Is there a way we can customize the image tags and names produced by Azure ML?
Also, is it possible to push the images to private registry rather than container registry (the default one in azure ML)?

Or if we can download image from container registry to Jfrog in Azure Devops?

I need to do this to write deploy pipeline in AzDO. I am not AZML expert, want to help team as DevOps who has started using AZML newly and not aware of how to set this up.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the customize the image tags that you are trying.

Comment: The images produced by AzML are pushed to ACR with some non custom names(Ex. azureml_a26611b65cd8c55b8a6203eheudo90 in our case) and tags(latest and 1,2,3 etc). If I have to write my AZDO standard pipeline to deploy that image to AKS cluster that we are already using, we want some custom naming convention and tags on image.
Is it possible to do that during image build in AzML?

Comment: Also, how can I pass model to that image(downloaded from ACR) while deploying to AKS? All that is usually taken care by AzML during deployment, but we do not want to use AzML deployment as it add lots of stuff to default namespace and does so much of work which is like a blind spot for Ops teams to manage in production.

Answer (score 0):

When registering model in AML generally model versions auto-increment. For more flexible indicators of model quality you can [customize tags](https://giangnt2.medium.com/implementing-many-models-at-scale-with-spark-3-x-databricks-synapse-and-azure-ml-3697731d7487) & properties. You could also put an evaluation gate in to run pre-registration.

MLOps patterns using azdo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOpsPython/blob/74885302c4f8382992b964615b0b989a74578ddc/.pipelines/diabetes_regression-ci-image.yml).